# How to correctly write definite time integration of this function?

Tags: integration, notation, physics

Last time I saw an integral was something like 10 years ago, and I am having doubts about the notation I should use. I want to describe the evolution of the volume difference between two cylinders over time (representing the elastic recoil of the aorta). Below is a graphical representation:

[image: aortic root]

So taking $R$ as the radius at time $t_0$, and $r$ as the radius at time $t_1$, I can describe the difference between the cylinders (which is in fact equal to flow) defined from those radii as follows:

$$\dot{Q}_\text{aorta} = \pi hR^2 - \pi hr^2$$

Now, my problem is just that I would like to express that as a definite integral over time instead of the $F(b)-F(a)$ form. I now that the function  will be $2\pi hr$.

but, $\displaystyle\dot{Q}_\text{aorta}=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\cdots$?

My problem especially lies as in how to write the variable: $\dot{r}$? $r(t)$?

And how about the $d$ part: $dt$? $dr(t)$? $\dfrac{dr}{dt}$?

I am sorry if this seems stupid, but I was not able to find some definite info.

Comment: It would be $\int{2\pi r \cdot h \cdot  dr}$

Comment: @hjpotter92 but then how should I express boundaries? $\int_{r_0}^{r_1}$ ? Since $r$ is in fact a function of time, I would have expected time to appear somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of understanding; let's assume $r(t) = at^2 + bt + c$ to be the radial change wrt time.

You'll get the integral to be:

$$\begin{align}
I &= \int_{r_1}^{r_2}{2 \pi \cdot r \cdot h \cdot dr} \\
&= 2\pi h \int_{t_1}^{t_2}{(at^2 + bt + c)\left[(2at + b)dt\right]}
\end{align}$$

In other words:

$$ \dfrac{dr}{dt} = 2at + b \\
\equiv dr = (2at + b) dt$$